# How to collect form data (text arrays) after submitting using POST method

Tags: php, html

how to use POST method with arrays in PHP? I have never learnt PHP, so don't have a clue how to make it. I have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="email-script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="emailForm"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" >
        <div id="nameError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">nameError</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surame" >
        <div id="nameError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">nameError</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control"  placeholder="Phone" >
        <div id="subjectError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">subjectError</div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label>First Level Category</label><br />
 <select id="first_level" name="first_level[]" multiple class="form-control">
 <?php
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  echo '<option value="'.$row["first_level_category_id"].'">'.$row["first_level_category_name"].'</option>';
 }
 ?>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Second Level Category</label><br />
 <select id="second_level" name="second_level[]" multiple class="form-control">

 </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Third Level Category</label><br />
 <select id="third_level" name="third_level[]" multiple class="form-control">

 </select>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" class="form-control">
                            <div id="attachmentError" style="color: red;font-size: 14px;display: none">attachmentError</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit">
                            <center><input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validateEmailSendForm();" class="btn btn-success" value="SUBMIT"></center>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Then I am collecting submited data from the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $date = $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $uploadStatus = 1;
```

I've found out how to collect data with text values, like `name, phone,` etc. But I don't know how to collect data with text arrays like `first_level[], second_level[] and third_level[]`. I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some hints.

Comment: _"But I don't know how to post text arrays like first_level[], second_level[] and third_level[]."_ - not even the phrasing makes much sense here ... The one _doing_ the POST-ing, is your browser, when you submit that form. What you actually want to know now - pretty unclear.

Comment: Sorry, for being unclear. Edited.

Comment: Form fields with the name `foo[]`, will result in PHP creating an _array_ in `$_POST['foo]`. _"But I don't know how to collect data"_ - it has already been "collected" for you, by PHP. All you need to do now, is _process_ this data in whatever way makes sense to you.